# Weird styling in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have some html here which works fine on Firefox, but when I tested them on Chrome, those which don't include the div work fine, but the other pages are totally disassembled! For example, here is the login code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>login</title>
    <meta name="author" content="lenovo" />
    <style>
    .div {
        position:absolute;
        top:"30px";
        border:1px solid #a1a1a1;
        padding:10px 40px; 
        background:white;
        width:300px;
        height:350px;
        border-radius:2px;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="left: 890px">
<p style="font-size: 27px; position: relative; left: -10px"> <font face="century gothic"> <b>Sign In</b> </font></p>
<p style="font-size: 16px; position: relative; left: -10px"><font face="century gothic"> <b>Email</b></font> </p>
<form>
    <input type="text"; name="email"; style="width: 300px; background-color: white" class="left"/>
</form>
<br />
<p style="font-size: 16px; position: relative; left: -10px"><font face="century gothic"> <b>Password</b></font> </p>
<form>
    <input type="text"; name="Password"; style="width: 300px; background-color: white" class="left"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox"; class="" /> Remember me <br />

</form>
<br />


<a href="home.html"><button class="left" style="color: white; background-color: blue; width: 100px; height: 40px" type="button" ><b>Sign In</b></button></a>

<br />
</div>
</body>
```

---

Chrome: [image: Chrome]

Firefox: [image: Firefox]

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle and narrow down the code that is causing the problem? That's a lot of code you have there…

Comment: Did you really have the style block in between your body and head or is it just pasted wrong? It should be inside head (or body)

Comment: No, it's pasted wrong

Comment: So - can you explain in more detail what you are having trouble with?   I pasted your code here (http://jsfiddle.net/42Y8V/).   Seems to work just fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: on chrome, I have an extra box, in the left side, besides the right one.. 2 containers appear on the page, one contains the sign-in form, the other one, nothing

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of what you are experiencing?  I see the exact same results in IE / FF / Chrome.

Comment: Additionally...  I see you have defined a class `.div`, however I don't see any elements that are using that class.

Comment: `type="text";` (and other attributes) shouldn't have semicolons.

Comment: I added the screenshots to the post, could'nt upload them here, sorry

Comment: I added the screenshots for you. And it went thru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so based on your screenshots, this is what I think is happening.   You are attempting to style the `div` on your form.   There must be other elements on the page that must be affected by your styling, causing the strange behavior.

Try this - hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Update your HTML like so:

```
<div class="myForm" style="left: 890px">
```

And then update your CSS to:

```
.myForm
{
    position:absolute;
    top:"30px";
    border:1px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding:10px 40px; 
    background:white;
    width:300px;
    height:350px;
    border-radius:2px;
 }
```

Basically, all I've done is assigned a specific class name to your form, and then changed the CSS to that class name as well.   This way, you can be sure what is being targeted by your code.

Comment: I have other elements, but I removed them from the code in here,. I updated the HTML, but it has the same problem , I removed all other elements  from the code and tested it, but still the same problem occures

Comment: The issue I'm seeing is that the code you've provided doesn't technically produce the results in your screenshot.   In your code, you have defined a CSS class `.div` which is a white, 300x350 box.   You NEVER reference this class in your HTML.   As your code is written, all the elements will sit off to the left of the page.   Now, if you change `.div` to `div` in your CSS, THEN everything moves over to the right as expected.   In any case, I can't reproduce any extra boxes on the screen with the code you've given (the updated code).   I'm using IE11, FF, Chrome...  all work fine.

Comment: Are you able to provide us with a public link to view the page?   I'd love to see what the actual source code looks like.

Comment: I created a class and used it in the div tag, now it works fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting a class called div instead of the tag. Remove the leading dot and you should be fine.

Comment: How did you link your css file?

Comment: with div tag around the section